# Nuxt environment variable exposed in Production

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a .env file with all my secret connection strings. When I build and deploy it to production environment on Azure App Service, I can see all my .env content inside /_nuxt/app.c0ab03c.js

How can I fix it? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using the [dotenv-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/dotenv-module) from Nuxt.

If yes, then, the module takes in an option to make only a certain set of environment variables available in Nuxt's context.

E.g.

```
export default {
  buildModules: [
    ['@nuxtjs/dotenv', { only: ['some_env_variable_key'] }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Prashant, Yes I think I'm mixing up nuxtjs/dotenv and dotenv. From my understanding they both read from '.env' file but nuxtjs/dotenv will load the environment variable to context so that the environment variable will be visible on front-end, am I correct? Thanks!

Comment: @Prashant I am not using @nuxtjs/dotenv and still I have same issue